# Select and store element from HTML table/JSON parsed object array

Tags: javascript, html, sql, json, select

I have an HTML table displaying the titles and sources of news articles. The news articles come from a JSON object. I can't figure out how to make it save the specific article you click the 'submit' button next to (=extract the appropriate element from a JSON array). I'd want to return/save it to some sort of output that I can then store in SQL. Please help?

The table looks like this:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Article</th>
        <th>News Source</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for article in articles.articles %}
            <tr>
                <div id = {{ article.title }}>
                <td><a href = {{ article.url }}>{{ article.title }}</a></td>
                <td>{{ article.source.name }}</td>
                </div>
                <td><form method="post"><button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Save to profile</button></form></td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Note that `<div>` is invalid child of `<tr>` and parent of `<td>`

Comment: Not sure why you can't put what you need in your form. Can use ajax to submit it